# Python Loop not breaking correctly

Tags: python, loops, recursion, while-loop, break

I have a simple loop that is not breaking as expected.

I believe that the root cause might be due to my loop being recursive. I have a plethora of functions that are activated by a menu. Calling the functions works fine, however, the issue occurs when I try to leave a function. If I call the function twice I have to close it twice, the same happens if I call it thrice.

Here is my code:

```
tweetsearch():
    global b
    b += 1
    tweepylanguages = ['English:en', 'Arabic:ar', 'Bengali:bn', 'Czech:cs', 'Danish:da', 'German:de', 'Greek:el', 'Spanish:es', 'Persian:fa', 'Finnish:fi', 'Filipino:fil', 'French:fr', 'Hebrew:he', 'Hindi:hi', 'Hungarian:hu', 'Indonesia:id', 'Italian:it', 'Japanese:ja', 'Korean:ko', 'Malay:msa', 'Dutch:nl', 'Norwegian:no', 'Polish:pl', 'Portuguese:pt', 'Romanian:ro', 'Russian:ru', 'Swedish:sv', 'Thai:th', 'Turkish:tr', 'Ukrainian:uk', 'Urdu:ur', 'Vietnamese:vi', 'Chinese(Simplifed):zh-cn', 'Chinese(Traditional):zh-tw']    
    topic=input('What would you like to search?')
    for x in tweepylanguages:
                       print (x)
    language=input('What language would you like to search in?')
    number=input("How many tweets would to like to look at? (1-100)")
    for tweet in api.search(q=topic, lang=language, rpp=number):
                 printTweet(f'Tweet Id: {tweet.id} of {tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}')
             
    while True:
        question = input("Would you like to look up another topic?   (yes/no)").lower()
        if question == 'yes':
            tweetsearch()
            continue
        elif question == 'no':  
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter either (yes/no)')
```

How can I fix the while loop so that it breaks correctly?

Comment: It's not recursive if the loop  is outside the function.

Comment: Does the indentation in the question match your actual code? The `while` loop you posted is not inside the function.

Comment: Is `printTweet` a valid statement?

Comment: printTweet is a valid statement, and thank you for pointing out the indentation issue, I am still getting use to formatting for this site.